# How to create a radial gradient around navigation?

Tags: html, css

[image]

See the radial gradient flowing around the center of the navigation?  Lets suppose I made a `div` that is the navigation.  How would I create a gradient that looks like in the picture?

Note: Look at the background *behind* the menu.

Comment: Looks like an inner shadow/glow effect to me...

Comment: I know how to create it in Photoshop, if that's what you're saying.

Comment: @Yep - Take a look at: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yeah, I've used that before.  I know how to create the gradient itself, I just don't know how to center it right in the middle of my navigation div.  That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far? Some of the examples on that site are very similar to what you have above (which I assume is the glass effect)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'm thinking my question wasn't clear. I have the navigation bar already created.  So lets ignore the appearance of the navigation for now.  Lets just say I have an object (in this case the navigation) in a single div that stretches across the entire top of the webpage.  My question is how I can create a radial gradient (such as `-webkit-radial-gradient`) that has it's focal point in the center of the div (navigation).  Then I can just use a `rgba` color and fade the gradient into transparency.  Get what I'm trying to ask?

Comment: Well, I'm confused. See @HerrSerker's example in his answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: See my updated image?  I'm looking on how to achieve *that* gradient.

Comment: Oh right. That's very hard to see (the gradient). I kept looking at the actual menu itself. `:s`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you talk about the lighter brown glow that is behind the navigation you can do this with CSS3...: http://jsfiddle.net/Jg8ZC/

```
  background: #45392d;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #624a36 0%, #45392d 80%); /* New WebKit syntax */  
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #624a36 0%, #45392d 80%);  /* Firefox */  
  background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #624a36 0%, #45392d 80%); /* IE10+ */  
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #624a36 0%, #45392d 80%); /* Opera (13?) */  
  background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #624a36 0%, #45392d 80%; /* standard syntax */
```

This way it will work in every modern browser.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm sort of looking for.  The only problem is getting that behind the navigation, instead of being centered in the page.

Comment: @Yep: you could use `ul.nav:before { position: absoulte; top:0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 300px; z-index: -1; background: theGradients}`

Comment: I'll look into it, but this is definitely what I was trying to do.  Thanks!

Comment: @Yep - Add `background-position: num num;` to the background element: http://jsfiddle.net/Jg8ZC/4/

Comment:  I come from the future to tell you it doesn't work in every modern browser anymore. These `contain` and `cover` keywords are deprecated now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient#Values

Answer (score 1):

This is not a radial gradient. It seems to be a graphic.

As for CSS, Look her http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/radial-gradients/ or in google. Theres plenty of resources out there

Here is a editor http://www.westciv.com/tools/radialgradients/index.html

[Example](http://www.westciv.com/tools/radialgradients/index.html#background-image%3a%20radial-gradient%2850%25%2050%25,%20circle%20cover,%20#ababab,%20#7a5647%200%25,#1c1815%20100%25%29)

Comment: I know it's a graphic.  Using some CSS I could easily export that from Photoshop and set it as a background. However, that's not what I want.  I want to use `-webkit-radial-gradient` (or similar) to create that effect, with the center located right in the middle of the navigation div.

Comment: Note, for some reason it's not working in FF7, but works fine in Chrome (latest).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with CSS, you could use a [radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-radial-gradient):

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(contain, #bf8230 0%, #a65f00 100px);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4wyak/1/) (jsFiddle).

The above will create a circular glow with a radius of 100px centered in the padding-box of the `<div>`.

If you want to make a glow "around" an element, you could nest an element with a semitransparent gradient background inside one with a solid background, as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4wyak/2/). You'd have to make sure that the nested element doesn't fill its container, and that its padding box can include the entire glow, or it will appear "cut off".

(The example was only done for Chrome Beta, and will probably require appropriate vendor prefix incantations and testing for other browsers.)